# I want to learn to automate the creation of legal documents (in Word) using a template I possess

Tags: python, automation, ms-word

I have a template for a legal document that I need to create copies of. While most of the legal text will remain the same for each copy, what changes is small counter-party related details (like name, age, address, contract amount etc).

I am hoping there is a way by which I can store the changing counter-party details in a single (say Excel) file, and generate the copy of the legal document using a script of some sort.

I am familiar with C. I don't know any scripting, but I think I can pick it up quickly. I am especially keen on learning Python (if that is the easiest way to solve this problem).

Comment: you should clarify if you want doc or docx. They have very different answers

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using word, try Mail Merge.

It allows you to use a database and insert the data into the document for each row in the database.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/word-mail-merge-a-walk-through-the-process-HA001034920.aspx

That should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks Jaime, I used Mail Merge and that works great for single documents and many counterparties. However, in the case that I need to create copies of many documents for many counterparties, is there a one-step solution? I can concatenate all the docs into one large doc and do a Mail Merge, but that seems horribly inelegant (not to mention a nightmare to print on letterheads etc)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using docx (as opposed to doc), I'd suggest you take a look at CustomXML content control databinding.

Easy to work with in Java (via docx4j), and in .NET languages (via OpenXML SDK); maybe others can comment on other language bindings.